# how to submit and retrieve data with Curl?

Tags: php, dom, curl

I am trying Curl in PHP for the first time, the reason is I want to scrape results from this page :http://www.lldj.com/pastresult.php . This site posts weekly lotto results since 2002 and has a simple submit form ( Date ).

A submit button : Name = Button / value = Submit
Select drop down : Name = Draw & Options #( 1 - 1097 ) // Represent draw number

I can go over it manually but i thought why don't i use a simple script and make it easier as I am also interested in testing how to submit data using PHP/ CURL and retrieve results.

I have used DOM PHP for scraping and I am comfortable using the syntax .
I wonder if I should use Curl and DOM together or this can be achieved with CURL.

What I have so far ;

```
include'dom.php';
$post_data['draw'] = '1097';
$post_data['button'] = 'Submit';

//traverse array and prepare data for posting (key1=value1)
foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value) {
$post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
}

//create the final string to be posted using implode()
$post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);

//create cURL connection
$curl_connection = 
curl_init('http://www.lldj.com/pastresult.php');

//set options
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
//set data to be posted
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

 //perform our request
$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);

 //show information regarding the request
 print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_connection));
echo curl_errno($curl_connection) . '-' . 
            curl_error($curl_connection);
```

After Submitting Data / scrape

```
$t = $curl_connection->find('table',0); // ?? usualy referes to file_get_content Var
$data = $t->find('tr');

foreach($data as $n) {
$tds = $n->find('td');

$dataRows = array();

$dataRows['num'] =  $tds[0]->find('img',0)->href;

var_dump($dataRows);
}
```

Can someone point on whether this is correct ? How can you set to automatically increase the submit value then repeat the process ( eg, submit darw = 1 then draw =2 ect. )
Thanks

Comment: `$t = $curl_connection->find('table',0);` That's not PHP core code. I think you have been missing to tell us the details

Comment: $html = file_get_html('URL');
$t = $html->find("table",0);
But what is then the point of using CURL? as the url will bring you to the first page and not the page with submitted data...

Comment: Curl is not required. Check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16914173/171318) below

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php   
  while(true){

   for($i=1;$i<5000;$i++){

$post_data['draw'] = $i; // will change every time like 1,2,3,4
$post_data['button'] = 'Submit';

//traverse array and prepare data for posting (key1=value1)
foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value) {
$post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
}

//create the final string to be posted using implode()
$post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);

//create cURL connection
$curl_connection = 
curl_init('http://www.lldj.com/pastresult.php');

//set options
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
//set data to be posted
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

 //perform our request
$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);

 //show information regarding the request
 print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_connection));
echo curl_errno($curl_connection) . '-' . 
            curl_error($curl_connection);
```

// start your scrap

```
$t = $curl_connection->find('table',0); // ?? usualy referes to file_get_content Var
$data = $t->find('tr');

foreach($data as $n) {
$tds = $n->find('td');

$dataRows = array();

$dataRows['num'] =  $tds[0]->find('img',0)->href;

var_dump($dataRows);
}
```

} for loop end here

```
}?>
```

Here just skeleton to use curl in continuously with changed id you can set it your way.

also please make sure to clear you variable after fetch data.

use  like

```
...
curl_close($ch);
unset($fields_string);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

**Load the page**

The prefered way to grab remote content is `file_get_contents()`. Use:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.lldj.com/pastresult.php');
```

Thats's it.

---

**Get content from the page**

To get content from the page you will usually use `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath`:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$selector = new DOMXpath($doc);

// xpath query
$result = $selector->query('YOUR QUERY');
```

Comment: this would be appropriate to scrape the table using xpath selectors, but i think you are missing the point that you need to submit a value first then retrieve the update table values..

Comment: Yes I missed this. So curl would be fine that's true